# splitting hold out data for calibration model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to split my hold out further data-set for fitting the calibration model.. but i dont have idea on how to split it further. see below

I have trained my model with below

```
Train =  pd.read_csv("Test.csv")
ytrain = Train['Fraud']
Xtrain = Train.drop( ['Fraud'], axis = 1 )
```

How can i further split the below data further to fit my calibration model

```
Test = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")
ytest = Test['Fraud']
Xtest = Test.drop( ['Fraud'], axis = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `CalibratedClassifierCV()`, it will calibrate based on the test samples used for cross validation. If you want to manually choose what data to use for calibration, you can set the parameter `cv="prefit"` and then `.fit` the `CalibratedClassifierCV` on that new validation set.